# LinkedIn share API fails with "Response to preflight request doesn't pass"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, linkedin-api

i am using api call to share post on company page , when i do this from localhost it works fine, but when i put it on live VPS it fails

`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin "MY ADDRESS I REMOVED FOR MY SECURITY" is therefore not allowed access.`

I have googled it and found that it is a problem with the CORS headers , i have tried to add `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in .htaccess i set but still nothing, any and all pointers or fixes would be appreciated , thanks

i use php 5.6 and apache 2.4.18

Comment: How are you making this API call?

Comment: i am using SimpleLinkedIn from https://github.com/EJTH/SLinkedIn and to add it works fine on localhost

Comment: Ok so i managed to fix this error by adding headers not only to .htaccess but also to my ajax calls and it is working, so if you have same error fix it by adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" headers in ajax call

Comment: Hey, JozefBarca: Seems right!  Why don't you work that out into an answer, and mark it as correct, so others can be helped with the same problem?  (Or, I can, if you'd like.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this as answer so that anyone can find it. As @HoldOffHunger suggeted.
Ok so i managed to fix this error by adding headers not only to `.htaccess` but also to my ajax calls and it is working, so if you have same error fix it by adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` headers in ajax call, change "*" with your origin.